# RoR get key name from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I am fairly new to RoR and to working with hashes. I am trying to get the name keys from a hash so that I can print them on the page. I keep getting an undefined method for the hash. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate some guidance.

When I run this:

```
- position_names = @contest.positions.map(&:name)
= position_names
```

I get this:

```
undefined method 'name' for {"name"=>"P", num=>"3", "ep"=>["SP", "RP"]}:Hash
```

What should I do here and what would be the best way to get the name **keys** from a hash?

Comment: You just want an array of the keys?

Comment: If you look at http://pastebin.com/tKwMpD1B you will see that there are a few name keys. I would like to print out name1 name2 name3 instead of what you see on pastebin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if @contest.positions returns hash then you can get the list by this:-

```
@contest.positions.keys
```

Edited:

Try doing this:-

```
 names = []
 names = @contest.positions.map {|array| array["name"]}
```

This will give you all the names and you can modify the way you want to use.

Comment: @contest.positions.name returns undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x007fb263b48dc8>

Comment: and what does @contest.positions return?